# How does Virtual File System (VSI) File handling work in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: gdal, arcgis-pro

There are a few references to GDAL VSI urls in the ESRI documentation, for example [here](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/imagery/workflows/best-practices/storing-imagery-in-the-cloud.htm) but no documentation on how it's implemented or used.

For instance, adding  `/vsizip//vsicurl/https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/andorra-latest-free.shp.zip` into the `add Data From Path` does not work in ArcGIS Pro, but I can add this string into the `Add Vector Layer` in QGIS and it loads without any issue